# Why function argument cannot be polymorphic in Ocaml?

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, parametric-polymorphism

say if I have the following function:

```
let rejected f = (f 1, f "hi");;
```

It is rejected by the type checker, I don't really understand why the type check reject it. Since f can be a polymorphic function (say `id`), and the type checker should allow it. Can somebody explain?

Comment: how would you write an `f` that would work with both an `int` and a `string` here? (Besides `Fn.id` I guess)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to "let polymorphism", aka "prenex polymorphism", aka "ML-style polymorphism". Searching on this terms will give you some information about this.

In a layman terms, this is how type-inference works, and some point you need to stop generalize, and fix your type variables. In ML-style polymorphism this is done on a `let` level. As a consequence, function inside a let binding should be used uniformly, i.e., with the same parameters. If it is a problem for you, then you can overcome it using records, objects or (maybe) some other features of the language. Here is an excerpt from OCaml [FAQ](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/faq/core.en.html):

> How to write a function with polymorphic arguments? 
>   In ML, an argument
>   of a function cannot be polymorphic inside the body of the function;
>   hence the following typing:

```
let f (g : 'a -> 'a) x y = g x, g y 
val f : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a * 'a = <fun>
```

> The function is not as
>   polymorphic as we could have hoped. Nevertheless, in OCaml it is
>   possible to use first-order polymorphism. For this, you can use either
>   records or objects; in the case of records, you need to declare the
>   type before using it in the function.

```
let f (o : <g : 'a. 'a -> 'a>) x y = o#g x, o#g y
type id = { g : 'a. 'a -> 'a; }
let f r x y = r.g x, r.g y
```

Comment: Two other ways to do this: first-class modules and (I'd say the most elegant) GADTs. I'd say objects are a bad idea as they are heavier on the produced assembly.

Comment: @PatJ, can you please provide an example, of how `let f g x y = g x, g y` problem can be solved with GADTs?

Comment: After checking, it turns out I was wrong, I thought it was possible to simply declare first-order polymorphism inside a GADT definition. I still think it would be cool though.

Comment: the last example seems only useful when `g` is `Fn.id`. What kind of polymorphic function is useful since there is no notion of interface or trait in OCaml? It seems like useful polymorphic functions in OCaml have to be achieved via either passing methods as argument to the function (e.g. `let op ~add x y = add x y`) or using functors